# Axios doesn't get cookies/sessions from PHP with vue.js

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, woocommerce, axios

I have installed the CoCart Plugin which enables API for Woocommerce Cart. This works great but when visitors add something in the cart (for example me and then my friend) it'll mix our cart after a few products added, so for example I'm getting my friends cart somehow.

I'm using Axios in Vue so I've tried adding Crossdomain, true. And a few new headers. But it still mix the cart between users.

```
axios.get(SETTINGS.API_WOOCOMMERCE_CART + 'count-items', {
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
                    "cache-control": "no-cache",
                }
            })
.then(response => {
   cb(response.data);
})
.catch(e => {
    cb(e);
});
```

The result I want is not to mix the cart between users. (Sessions). I'm not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Client Side : Set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to each request sent to the server

Server side : Set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the exact base `url` of your application (exact mean all the details, port number, http or https and `localhost` is not considered the same as `127.0.0.1` ...)

Ps : Found this article should help you out, [Which CORS headers do you need to send an Authorization header?](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/09/12/authorization-header-and-cors/)

Comment: I've tried Credentials but did not work. I guess it's problem at the server side then. Will try later! Thank you!!